# Octet rule violation in Period 2 elements

Tags: periodic-trends

My textbook states,

> Period 2 elements typically obey the octet rule. Period 3 and later elements can expand their valence shells. Elements in Periods 5 and 6 of the p-block show variable valence (the inert-pair effect).

I was surprised that it said period 2 elements **typically** obey the octet rule. What are some circumstances in which period 2 elements break the octet rule? I though they couldn't because they don't have available d orbitals.

Comment: Related: [Which relatively simple molecules violate the octet rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32265/which-relatively-simple-molecules-violate-the-octet-rule)

Comment: If I could, I would "neutralize" a vote to close this question.  It is to me quite nontrivial.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50381/why-does-boron-only-need-6-valence-electrons-unlike-the-standard-8

Answer (score 1):

Typically the octet rule becomes less likely to work, regardless of the period, when we move to a group where there are too few valence electrons to go around.  Prominent examples in Period 2 include compounds of beryllium in Group 2 (such as the [fluoride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_fluoride), especially when gaseous or liquid) and boron in Group 13 (as in alkyl boranes like [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylborane)).  Carbon can also form species that are most stable with fewer electrons than the octet rule would predict, a "violation" most prominently seen in the [cyclopropenyl cation](https://www.google.com/amp/s/drmarkforeman.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/orbitals-of-c3h3-cation/amp/), where [another "rule" that is much more reliable when properly used](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_15%3A_Benzene_and_Aromaticity/15.03_Aromaticity_and_the_Huckel_4n___2_Rule) comes into play.